# VBA iterating over rows of range to create a dictionary of string to array?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel workbook with the third sheet looks like this:

```
A        B       C       D        E        F
1        test    test    test     test     test
1        test1   test1   test1    test1    test1
1        test2   test2   test2    test2    test2
2        test    test    test     test     test
3        test    test    test     test     test
4        test    test    test     test     test
5        test    test    test     test     test
6        test    test    test     test     test
```

And I want to create a dictionary where the first column is the key and the value is a collection of 5 arrays

```
key: 1
Value: [
    [test1   test1   test1    test1    test1]
    [test2   test2   test2    test2    test2]
    [test   test   test    test    test]
    [""   ""   ""    ""    ""]
    [""   ""   ""    ""    ""]
]

key: 2
Value: [
    [test   test   test    test    test]
    [""   ""   ""    ""    ""]
    [""   ""   ""    ""    ""]
    [""   ""   ""    ""    ""]
    [""   ""   ""    ""    ""]
]

etc.
```

I want to store this in a global variable before opening the form so that I can use it in functions like onclick():

```
Public donationDict As Scripting.Dictionary
Option Explicit
Sub ouvrir()
    Dim constData As Range
    Set constData = Range("thirdSheet!A:F")
    Dim rw As Range
    For Each rw In constData.rows

        If donationDict.Exists(rw(0)) Then
            donationDict(rw(0)).Add New Collection
        Else
            donationDict.Add rw(0), New Collection
        End If

    Next rw
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: The first column is not unique. All keys in a dictionary must be unique.

Comment: @ManuelLemos - I think the OP knows that already...

Comment: What is the problem you're having though?  You will need two loops - first to scan the rows an populate the Dictionary, then a second to "top up" any contained Collections which have <5 items.

Comment: I'm trying to do the equivalent of this python code:
`
for row in rows:
    if row[0] in mydict: mydict[row[0]].append(row)
    else: mydict[row[0]] = []
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out:

```vb
Option Explicit

Public donationDict As Scripting.Dictionary

Sub ouvrir()
    Dim data As Range, id, ws As Worksheet
    Dim rw As Range, arr(), numArrCols As Long
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("thirdSheet")
    Set data = ws.Range("A1:F" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    Set donationDict = New Scripting.Dictionary
    
    numArrCols = data.Columns.Count - 1
    ReDim arr(1 To numArrCols) 'empty array
    
    For Each rw In data.Rows
        id = rw.Cells(1).Value
        If Not donationDict.Exists(id) Then
            donationDict.Add id, New Collection 'new key: add key and empty collection
        End If
        donationDict(id).Add _
             OneDimension(rw.Cells(2).Resize(1, numArrCols).Value) 'add the row value as 1D array
    Next rw
    
    For Each id In donationDict.Keys
        Do While donationDict(id).Count < 5
            donationDict(id).Add arr 'add empty array
        Loop
    Next id
    
    ShowDict donationDict 'dump to Immediate window for review
End Sub

'convert a 2D [row] array to a 1D array
Function OneDimension(arr)
    OneDimension = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(arr))
End Function


Sub ShowDict(dict)
    Dim k, e
    For Each k In dict.Keys
        Debug.Print "Key: " & k
        Debug.Print "------------------------"
        For Each e In dict(k)
            Debug.Print , Join(e, ",")
        Next e
    Next k
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Just to be sure how do I access it? `donationDict("1")(1)` is giving a syntax error

Comment: `donationDict("1")(1)` by itself is not a full code, so what exactly are you doing?

Comment: `donationDict("1")` would correspond to a `Collection` - that has 5 Items, each of which is a 1-D array (1 to 5)  So try something like `Debug.Print donationDict("1")(1)(1)`

Comment: ah nevermind... I didn't know that VBA didn't support array access without assigning a variable. Thanks!